# Pageant fails to generate OpenSSH Config

Tags: windows, ssh, pageant

I want to be able to use the SSH Keys loaded in Pageant when using the built-in Open SSH client.

I tried running the command `pageant.exe --openssh-config %USERPROFILE%\.ssh\pageant.conf` like in the answer from the question [Using pageant with VSCode on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74394215/15528650). The problem is that Pageant shows a message box with "Couldn't load this key (unable to open file)".

I recently upgraded from an older version of Putty to version 0.78. I also tried version 0.77. I am running Windows 10 22H2.

Comment: I do not get any error, when I try your command-line. Though, when I try the same command with old Pageant 0.76, I get *"unrecognised command-line option
'--openssh-config'"*. If you run `pageant.exe` from the same command-line, where you get the error, what does its *About* box show? (make sure you close any running Pageant before trying) What does `%USERPROFILE%` resolve to? Don't you have some special characters in the username/path (maybe a space)?

Comment: If your getting an error about the public key then you need to investigate the reason the key cannot be read. Why don’t you just modify the OpenSSH configuration file manually?

Comment: You should ask a question ending with a `?` character.

Comment: Thank you very much for the tip to look at the About box @MartinPrikryl. It noticed that it was running version 0.74 that comes with TortoiseGit. When I specified the full path to the version of Pageant I installed myself, it worked.

Comment: TortoiseGit needs to be updated, as the most recent stable version [2.14.0] come with v0.78 of `pageant` ([screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/Ffyzxj9))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that when typing in pageant in the command prompt and looking in the About box it was starting version 0.74, which is too old. This version came with TortoiseGit.

The solution was to specify the full path to the up to date version I installed myself. Then it just worked.

Comment: TortoiseGit needs to be updated, as the most recent stable version [2.14.0] come with v0.78 of `pageant` ([screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/Ffyzxj9))